# Why is my domain stuck "verification pending" in Amazon SES?

Tags: openssl, amazon-ses

I'm trying to add Amazon SES service to my domain, but I'm having trouble verifying my domain with them. I've carefully followed [Amazon's instructions for Bring Your Own DKIM (BYODKIM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html#verify-domain-procedure) but the domain keeps getting stuck at "verification pending". I waited the full 72 hours to receive an "Email DKIM setup FAILURE" message from Amazon with the explanation, "We have not been able to detect the required DNS records in your DNS settings." I have doublechecked everything, especially in DNS, and carefully repeated the setup procedure from scratch but still can't get my domain verified. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**2023-08-20 update**: The below is no longer true, because Amazon SES has added support for PKCS #8 formatted private keys. I would therefore expect PKCS #8 formatted private keys to function properly without causing the domain to get stuck "verification pending".

**What was true in 2022 but is now no longer true:** As of OpenSSL 3.0, the `openssl genrsa` command produces PKCS #8 formatted private keys by default, which Amazon SES does not support. Amazon SES BYODKIM private keys [are required to be in PKCS #1 format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-dkim.html).

To fix this issue, regenerate the keypair while specifying the `-traditional` option to `openssl genrsa`, and then rebuild the Amazon SES configuration using that keypair. This option is [new in OpenSSL 3.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-genrsa.html).

Comment: The troubleshooting DKIM page linked says "The private key has to be in either PKCS #1 or PKCS #8 format" though

Comment: @kehers Ah, Amazon SES has since added support for PKCS #8 formatted private keys. That support did not exist last year: https://web.archive.org/web/20220817132151/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-dkim.html

I will update this answer accordingly. Thanks.